# Sending and returning my PHP SOAP request from a function

Tags: php, soap

I've written a function like so:

```
/**
   * Send the soap request to complemar
   * @method  SendSoapRequest
   * @param   string          $method       The requst action
   * @param   string          $requestData  The xml
   * @access  private
   */
  private function SOAPRequest( $method, $requestData ){
    /** Run the soap request */
        $result = $this->SOAPClient->call( $method, $requestData, 'xsi' );
    /** Now check if there are errors or faults */
        if( $this->SOAPClient->fault ){
      /** Save the fault to the last fault message */
      $this->SOAPLastFault = print_r( $result, true );
      /** Output the error */
      echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>'.$this->SOAPLastFault.'</pre>';
      /** Return false */
            return false;
        } else {
      /** Check soap for erros */
      $this->SOAPErrors = $this->SOAPClient->getError();
      /** Check soaps return for a message */
            if( $this->SOAPErrors ){
        /** we have an error output it */
                echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $error . '</pre>';
        /** return false */
                return false;
            }
        }
    /** No errors return the result */
        return $result;
    }
```

I'm trying to send the soap request thats already built above, take the request back in another file and set it in the db. I'm confused on what I should try.

The file I want to write the send and return is below.

```
class ComplemarUpdateOrderStatus extends \Framework\Event\Cronjob
{
  protected static $prefix = "[ComplemarUpdateOrderStatus]: ";

  public static function run( data ){
    /** Log that we started */
    self::logMessage("Started!");
  }

  {

  }
```

Should I `SoapClient::__doRequest`???

Any help would be appreciated. I'm very confused.